# wp_enqueue_scripts, wp_register_scripts, wp_print_scripts: i'm confused

Tags: css, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

- I've been reading up a bit on this subject, but the more I read - the more confused I get.
- Can someone explain to me in short what's the exact difference between `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `wp_register_scripts` and `wp_print_scripts`?
- For example, I have the following code in my functions.php - and it's working, but I do not understand why I can not use `wp_print_scripts` for the stylesheets, whereas the code still works if I use `wp_enqueue_scripts` for the javascript files:

  ```
  add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'add_my_js');
  function add_my_js(){
      if(!is_admin()){
          wp_enqueue_script('default',  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/default.js', array('jquery'));
      }
  }

  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_stylesheet');
  function add_my_stylesheet() {
      wp_register_style('default', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url'));
      wp_enqueue_style( 'default');
  }
  ```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`wp_print_scripts` is the action that runs when scripts are output to the template. `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` are functions for registering/enqueueing scripts to be output when `wp_print_scripts` runs.

you can't register or enqueue styles in the `wp_print_scripts` action hook because styles have already been output in the `wp_print_styles` hook, which runs before `wp_print_scripts`.

refer to the [action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to see the order things are executed in in a request:

```
22. wp_head
23. wp_enqueue_scripts
24. wp_print_styles
25. wp_print_scripts
```

Comment: So then, what is the difference between wp_enqueue_script and wp_register_script?

Comment: wp_register_script registers the script with WordPress, but does not add it to the queue. If you don't also call wp_enqueue_script, the script will not appear. The purpose of this is to let you register your script once, then later conditionally enqueue it somewhere else in your code. This is useful for plugin developers where a script may be enqueued in multiple places within the code. You can also just enqueue your script directly without registering it.