# is_page() or is_single not working

Tags: functions, conditional-tags

Im trying to clean up my scripts and I'm using a function to but ran into a problem with using both !is_page or !is_single to only show certain scripts on singles and pages. What did I do wrong here.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
if ( !is_page() ) {
wp_deregister_script( 'thickbox' );
wp_deregister_script( 'shutter' );
wp_deregister_script( 'swfobject' );
wp_deregister_script( 'ngg-slideshow' );
wp_deregister_script( 'ngg_script' );
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-shuffle' );
  }
elseif ( !is_single() || !is_page()) {
wp_deregister_script( 'autosize_js' );
wp_deregister_script( 'admin_js' );
 }
}
```

Comment: What was the goal and what is the current behavior? Also, did you really mean `elseif`? I think you just wanted `if` for that second one.

Comment: reconsider the 'elseif' condition  as your one is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably because `wp_print_scripts` is too late to deregister scripts as this is when they are outputted to the template.

You should consider using `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `wp_register_script` instead.
This question may help:

[wp_enqueue_scripts, wp_register_scripts, wp_print_scripts: i'm confused](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36744/wp-enqueue-scripts-wp-register-scripts-wp-print-scripts-im-confused)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you should **accept** it, by clicking the checkmark below the vote count.